# smooth scrolling of imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have added the images to scrollview dynamically. Following is the code:

```
-(void)displayimages {
    for (int i=0; i<[featuredarray count]; i++) {
        NSString *image=[[featuredarray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"img"];

        if (i==0) {
            webview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*290+15, 0, 270, 380)];
        }
        else {
            webview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*290+15, 0, 270, 380)];
        }
        webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        webview.layer.borderWidth=4;
        webview.layer.cornerRadius=4;
        webview.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
        [webview setTag:i];
        webview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:image];
        [webview setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage 
           imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        [scroll addSubview:webview];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlefirstTap:)];
        tap1.delegate=self;
        tap1.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
        [webview addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
        [tap1 release];
        [webview release];
   }

   pages.defersCurrentPageDisplay=YES;
   scroll.delegate =self;

   scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(290*[featuredarray count],300);
   scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
   pages.numberOfPages = [featuredarray count]-1;
   pages.currentPage =0;
}

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    int gallerypage = scrollView.contentOffset.x /scrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGRect frame = scroll.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width-15*gallerypage;
    NSLog(@"frame.origin.x..%f",frame.origin.x);
    frame.origin.y =0;
    [scroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    int gallerypage = scrollView.contentOffset.x /scrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGRect frame = scroll.frame;
    frame.origin.x=gallerypage*290;
    frame.origin.y =0;
    [scroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

It is showing the images well when I use pagecontroller action

```
-(IBAction)pagecontrolaction:(id)sender {
    int page = pages.currentPage;
    CGRect frame = scroll.frame;
    frame.origin.x=page*290;
    frame.origin.y =0;
    [scroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

but when I used touch event to imageview then it is not displaying the images smoothly. It gets stuck during scrolling.

[image]

These are the preview which shows the current image with the start of second image.

Comment: What does “It gets stuck” mean?  Does your app hang?  Does it pause for a fraction of a second and then resume scrolling?  Does it just stop with the new image partially on the screen when you lift your finger, instead of scrolling the new image entirely onto the screen?

Comment: set webview frame like my answer

Comment: It pause for a fraction and then scrolled @robmayoff

Comment: @robmayoff check this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWKdpHCykCs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: In your video, it doesn't look like a pause.  It looks like the scroll view jumps back and then forward again.

Comment: hmmm how to make scroll smoothing the same as its work fine with the page controller action @robmayoff

Comment: Does it still stutter if you remove your `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` and `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` methods?

Comment: then it doesn't show the image (http://www.fileswap.com/dl/8UF7RANTrD/) as it should be. Check this link it shows the image irregular @robmayoff

Comment: @MinkleGarg Try to use the same UITapGestureRecognizer without declare it each time,and use the tag to recognize which one tap.

Comment: check the tutorial here its works smoothly http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/

Comment: Try to increase the animation duration of [scroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES] then check what is happing

Comment: Simply you need to comment out your `scrollViewWillBeginDecelarating:` method and it will work. I think you are trying to accomplish the paging in your scrolling in `scrollViewDelegate` Methods. Why not try to make `pagesEnabled:` into your `scrollView` ? Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

The two methods: scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating contains two animation with different x position it is animated to:

```
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width-15*gallerypage;
```

and

```
frame.origin.x=gallerypage*290;
```

It is better if you could turn off either function: scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating or scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. Otherwise probably you should adjust the x position (must be in sync for both functions) it will be animated to.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i==0) {
            webview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, 270, 440)];
        }
        else {
            webview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, 270, 380)];
        }
```

Comment: It will display only one image at a time. but I need current image  + start of second image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your implementation for loading the images from a remote resource, thats where the biggest bottle neck lies.

I don't want to go into details but try to replace this line of code

```
[webview setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

With something more c.p.u friendly. Use a caching mechanism that employs multi-threading, what you want to do is move the heavy lifting (Downloading remote images) to another thread.

SDWebImage does a perfect job at this  https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
If you are a bit hard core, you can roll your own multi-threaded image downloader using

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue: completionHandler:]
```

And do the image loading in the block, Or even better `dispatch_async(queu, block)`

Comment: I think `setImageWithURL:` method will call itself in `NSURLConnection`. It's looking like the method from `AFNetworking`, a popular open source in github to handle network calls.

Comment: @DineshRaja I am not sure what it calls to be exactly, but what I am sure of is that this method is a synchronous call, synchronous calls are bad, even when pushed to a background thread, it is not proper multi-threading paradigm.

Comment: in `AFNetworking` that method `asynchronously` loads an image in background and sets the image in main thread. There is no other way in my opinion. check out this. http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Categories/UIImageView%28AFNetworking%29.html

Comment: I meant, `setImageWithURL:` is already an asynchronous call. So IMHO nothing to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [SYPaginator](https://github.com/soffes/SYPaginator) (SYPaginator is a horizontal TableView with lazy loading and view recycling.)

> Simple paging scroll view to make complicated tasks easier. We use
>   this in several of the Synthetic apps including Hipstamatic, D-Series,
>   and IncrediBooth.

If you need more perfomance you should give [MSCachedAsyncViewDrawing](https://github.com/mindsnacks/MSCachedAsyncViewDrawing) a try:

> Helper class that allows you to draw views (a)synchronously to a
>   UIImage with caching for great performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because your images are larger in size (MB) , and you fit them into that `CGRect` without resizing them that specific size, also it matters how many pictures you have loaded inside the scrollview , if you load many pictures it will take a lot of memory and it will slide slowly.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you are trying to show an image of larger size in that case you have to use cache to get the image there and try to load image from there.For better know how to use it..use SDwebimage thats the nice way to do it and it is fast.
You can read

1. Lazy Loading

   2.paging enabled.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Need any further help.Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you setting the frame when you start scrolling, but if I were in your place I would do the logic as per below:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    // do nothing
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    int gallerypage = scrollView.contentOffset.x /scrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat xoffset = 290 * gallerypage;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(xoffset, 0);
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely resize your image in background prior to loading it into UIImageView. Also you should set UIImageView content mode to the none-resizing one. It gave me significantly scrolling improvement after other ways were already implemented (async cache and others).